# Display sections based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I display sections based on dropdown selection? If I select 2018 to see just that photos which are from 2018? And same for 2017.

Do you have any idea? I checked tutorials but doesn't work. Every answer is appreciated!

Check my code below to understand:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selection').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == '2017') {
      $("#seventeen").show();
      $("#eighteen").hide();
    } else if (this.value == '2018') {
      $("#eighteen").show();
      $("#seventeen").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section_7" class="media_section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <div class="section_head_widget animatedParent">
          <h2 class="animated fadeInLeft">Media</h2>
          <h5 class="animated bounceInUp">photos &amp; videos</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select id='selection'>
               <option value="2018" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2018<span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></option>
               <option value="2017" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2017</option>
      </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--section_head_widget-->
    </div>
    <!--row-->

    <div class="row media_widget">
      <div id='eighteen' class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_01.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>Me Gusta</h6>
            INNA </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div id='eighteen' class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop2">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_02.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>poison in news</h6>
            35 photos
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div id='seventeen' class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop4">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_04.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>poison in news</h6>
            95 photos </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div id='eighteen' class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop5">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_05.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>photos by fans</h6>
            70 photos </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--container-->
</section>
<!--//media_section-->
```

[image]

Comment: You have three divs with an id of "eighteen". Ids should be unique. If you want multiple selections use "class" or a custom tag.

Comment: Ok, I changed from id='eighteen' into class="eighteen" .
And JS looks like this now:

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selection').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '2017')
      {
  $(".seventeen").show();
        $(".eighteen").hide();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '2018')
      {
        $(".eighteen").show();
  $(".seventeen").hide();
      }
    });
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much more generic

1. give each a class only used by those divs plus the year to each div.
   I use `<div class="year 2018 ...`
2. hide all when changing
3. change based on value without using IF
4. trigger change onload

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selection').on('change', function() {
    $("div.year").hide();
    $("div."+this.value).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section_7" class="media_section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <div class="section_head_widget animatedParent">
          <h2 class="animated fadeInLeft">Media</h2>
          <h5 class="animated bounceInUp">photos &amp; videos</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select id='selection'>
               <option value="2018" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2018<span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></option>
               <option value="2017" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2017</option>
      </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--section_head_widget-->
    </div>
    <!--row-->

    <div class="row media_widget">
      <div class="year 2018 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_01.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>Me Gusta</h6>
            INNA </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div class="year 2018 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop2">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_02.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>poison in news</h6>
            35 photos
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div class="year 2017 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop4">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_04.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>poison in news</h6>
            95 photos </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div class="year 2018 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop5">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_05.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>photos by fans</h6>
            70 photos </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--container-->
</section>
<!--//media_section-->
```

Comment: I don't think this the best because I have ".animatedParent" called in a lot of sections in my website and will change it everywhere :(

Comment: So use another class for all year divs

Comment: class="year 2018 ....

Comment: I did it and If I select "2017" nothing displayed .

Comment: See my update...

Comment: My JS `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selection').on('change', function() {
    $(".years").hide();
    $("."+this.value).show();
  }).change();
});`

Comment: It works for me. I have "year 2018 ..." and use $(".year").hide() - make sure you spell correctly

Comment: I copied and paste your JS . 
 And you changed the HTML  just in divs. Added: year 2017/18. And doesn't work when I select "2017" in dropdown.

Comment: Yes. You need to change the HTML to have proper classes. So instead of `id='eighteen' class="col-xs-12` have `class="year 2018 col-xs-12`

Comment: An it DOES work - Please run my snippet

Comment: yes I edited. Now I see it works but when I select "2017" those are hide and if I scoll it appears. why?

Comment: I have no idea. It works in the snippet with the code you have given. I have not applied bootstrap or other CSS you may have

Comment: If you add your CSS and frameworks perhaps I can see why

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code is close. As pointed out in the comments, `id` attributes should be unique - only used once on a page. So move the `seventeen` and `eighteen` to a `class` instead of an `id`.

Then we'll move the show/hide function to a separate function so we can call it at the start to only show the 2018 events.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selection').on('change', showYear);
});

function showYear(event) {
    var year = event ? event.target.value : "2018";
    if (year === '2017') {
      $(".seventeen").show();
      $(".eighteen").hide();
    } else if (year === '2018') {
      $(".eighteen").show();
      $(".seventeen").hide();
    }
}

showYear();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="section_7" class="media_section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <div class="section_head_widget animatedParent">
          <h2 class="animated fadeInLeft">Media</h2>
          <h5 class="animated bounceInUp">photos &amp; videos</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select id='selection'>
               <option value="2018" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2018<span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></option>
               <option value="2017" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">2017</option>
              </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--section_head_widget-->
    </div>
    <!--row-->

    <div class="row media_widget">
      <div class="eighteen col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_01.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>Me Gusta</h6>
            INNA </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div class="eighteen col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop2">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_02.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>poison in news</h6>
            35 photos
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div class="seventeen col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop4">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_04.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>poison in news</h6>
            95 photos </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->

      <div class="eighteen col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 animatedParent">
        <figure class="animated fadeInUp">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gal_pop5">
            <img src="assets/img/media/media_05.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
          <!--hyperlink-->
          <figcaption>
            <h6>photos by fans</h6>
            70 photos </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!--figure-->
      </div>
      <!--Column / media item-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--container-->
</section>
<!--//media_section-->
```

Comment: I dont't knwo why if I select 2017 it's empty, nothing displayed. And another question: If I have more than 2 years (in JS section) I have to add another if? Thanks.

Comment: @Andii not in my version. You just add years to the select and the divs

Answer (score -1):

I have tested your code and it is working fine. You have multiple div element with same id (id="eighteen") which is creating problem.
Try out the following code

HTML:

```
 <select name="" id="selection">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
   <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<div id="seventeen" style="display: none;">2017 Photos</div>
<div id="eighteen" style="display: none;">2018 Photos</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#selection').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == '2017')
  {
    $("#seventeen").show();
    $("#eighteen").hide();
  }
  else if ( this.value == '2018')
  {
    $("#eighteen").show();
    $("#seventeen").hide();
  }
});
```

});

Comment: there are more than one div from 2017 and from 2018 - you only allow one now

Comment: If you want to show multiple divs on dropdown selection you can use "class" .

Comment: i know. Already answered in answer and comment.

Comment: and change your javascript to

$('#selection').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == '2017')
  {
    $(".seventeen").show();
    $(".eighteen").hide();
  }
  else if ( this.value == '2018')
  {
    $(".eighteen").show();
    $(".seventeen").hide();
  }
});

Comment: Yes, i watched after posting answer.

Comment: Very inelegant. every time a year is added, the script has to be changed